# Inserting a variable in wsh.run command string

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want to have my VBScript input variable used in my
`makefile = objShell.run (""""""cmd /K CD "strFolderName" & dir /-n >     "strFolderName"\wk3result.txt"""""",1,True)` command.

I've tried `cmd /K cd '"strFolderName"'`… 
I get directory not found so I do not believe my variables `strFolder` name is being put into the `cmd` line code correctly.

Here is my script:

```
Const cTitle = "WK3 Assignment"

Dim objFSO, objFolder
Dim strFolderName, objShell
strFolderName = InputBox("Which Folder", cTitle)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderName) Then
    WScript.Echo "Folder is there"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Folder is not there"
End If


Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
makefile = objShell.run (""""""cmd /K CD "strFolderName" & dir /-n >      "strFolderName"\wk3result.txt"""""",1,True)
```

expecting to get a txt file with the dir results of the inputed folder

Comment: As you have found, calling cmd from a vbscript quickly leads to double-quote hell. I suggest instead you use the `FileSystemObject` all the way. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some `&` around your `strFolderName` variable in your `makefile` command string. It should look like this:

`"cmd /K CD """ & strFolderName & """ dir /-n > """ & strFolderName & "\wk3result.txt"""`

Entire command:

```
makefile = objShell.run ("cmd /K CD """ & strFolderName & """ dir /-n > """ & strFolderName & "\wk3result.txt""", 1, True)
```

Better yet, make a variable of your command in case you need to view it for troubleshooting:

```
Dim strCommand
strCommand = "cmd /K CD """ & strFolderName & """ dir /-n > """ & strFolderName & "\wk3result.txt"""
makefile = objShell.run(strCommand, 1, True)
```

This way you can check what the command is with `MsgBox strCommand`.

Comment: Thanks I had to add a & before the dir to get it to work. but all in all great thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad it's working. Please come back for your programming questions. Also, please accept the answer if you feel it answered your question. You can accept an answer using the gray check mark to the left of the answer.